Representation of Hessian in Augmented State-Space Filtering Problems
Question
Let $z_t := (x_t, x_{t-1}, x_t^2, x_{t-1}x_t,x_{t-1}x_t,x_{t-1}^2)$, and
$R(x_t) := \sum_{(i,j) \in \{\{0,1,2,3,4\} \otimes \{0,1,2,3,4\} : i+j \le 4\}} w_{i,j} x_t^i x_{t-1}^j$,
so $R(\cdot)$ is quartic in $x_t, x_{t-1}$, but quadratic in $z_t$.
In a second-order Taylor expansion of $R(z)$ around $R(z^*)$,
$R(z) = R(z^*) + J_R(z^*)(z - z^*) + 0.5 (z - z^*)^\prime H_R(z^*) (z - z^*) $
how do I express the Jacobian, $J_R$, and Hessian, $H_R$, of $R(z_t)$ to account for the fact that the terms in $z_t$ are functions of one-another?
Background
I have a difficult filtering problem I am working through.
Let $x_t$ and $y_t$ be scalar random variables.
The state-transition dynamics can be characterized by, $x_t | x_{t-1} \sim \mathcal{N}(\Phi x_{t-1},Q)$.
The measurement equation has the following dynamics, $y_t | y_{t-1}, x_t, x_{t-1} \stackrel{\text{approx}}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(A + B y_{t-1} + f(x_t,x_{t-1}), R(x_t,x_{t-1})),$ where $f(\cdot)$ is quadratic in $\tilde{x}_t := (x_t, x_{t-1})^\prime$, and $R(\cdot)$ is quartic in $\tilde{x}_t$. The approximation comes from matching the moments of a stochastic integral, but we can ignore that for now and assume it is exactly Gaussian.
My solution thus far has been to augment the state-space with the second-order terms of the states, $z_t := (\tilde{x}_t^\prime,vec(\tilde{x}_t^\prime \tilde{x}_t)^\prime)^\prime = (x_t, x_{t-1}, x_t^2, x_t x_{t-1},x_{t-1} x_t, x_{t-1}^2 )^\prime$. I can keep track of the moments of $z_t | z_{t-1}$ exactly, and then $f(\cdot)$ is affine in $z_t$, and $R(\cdot)$ is quadratic in $z_t$.
To the best of my understanding the Kalman Filter will break down in my setting when computing the covariance of the innovation. Let $f(z_t) = \alpha_f + \beta_f z_t$, and $\mathcal{Y}_{t-1} := \{y_{\tau}\}_{\tau = t_0}^{t-1}$ then
$S_t = \beta_f P_{t|t-1} \beta_f^\prime + \mathbb{E}[R(z_t) | \mathcal{Y}_{t-1}]$,
where $S_t := \mathbb{E}[(y_t - \mathbb{E}[y_t | \mathcal{Y}_{t-1}])(y_t - \mathbb{E}[y_t | \mathcal{Y}_{t-1}])^\prime |  \mathcal{Y}_{t-1}]$.
My current plan is take the expectation of the second-order Taylor expansion around $R(\hat{z}_{t|t-1})$,
$\mathbb{E}[R(z_t)|\mathcal{Y}_{t-1}] = \mathbb{E}[ R(\hat{z}_{t|t-1}) + J_R(\hat{z}_{t|t-1}) (z_t - \hat{z}_{t|t-1}) + 0.5 (z_t - \hat{z}_{t|t-1})^\prime H_R(\hat{z}_{t|t-1})(z_t - \hat{z}_{t|t-1}) |\mathcal{Y}_{t-1}] = R(\hat{z}_{t|t-1}) + 0.5  \ tr\{H_R(\hat{z}_{t|t-1}) P_{t|t-1}\}$
where $\hat{z}_{t|t-1} := \mathbb{E}[z_t | \mathcal{Y}_{t-1}]$,resulting in an exact innovation covariance formula,
$S_t = \beta_f P_{t|t-1} \beta_f^\prime + R(\hat{z}_{t|t-1}) + 0.5  \ tr\{H_R(\hat{z}_{t|t-1}) P_{t|t-1}\}$.
Finally, my question is how do I compute the Hessian $H_R(z_t)$ given that several elements of $z_t$ are functions of other elements? In particular if,
$R(z_t) = \sum_{(i,j) \in \{0,1,2,3,4\} \otimes \{0,1,2,3,4\}} w_{i,j} x_t^i x_{t-1}^j$,
how do I express the hessian of $R(z_t),$ $H_R(z_t)$?

The solution is to treat each element of $z_t$ as its own variables, $z_t = (a,b,c,d,e,f)$, where $a=x_t$, $b=x_{t-1}$, $c = x_t^2$, $d = e = x_{t-1}x_t$, and $f=x_{t-1}^2$.
When substituting $a, b, c, d, e,$ and $f$ into $R(z_t)$, you try to express each term as a function solely of the second-order elements, $c, d, e,$ and $f$ before substituting in the lower-order elements, $a$ and $b$. For example, $x_{t-1}x_t^2 \rightarrow bc$, rather than $x_{t-1}x_t^2 \rightarrow a^2 b$. This leads to the nice property that the Hessian does not depend on $z_t$.
Also because $d=e$, when substituting both $d$ and $e$ into $R(z_t)$, the coefficient is divided in half to account for the fact that $d+e = 2 x_{t-1} x_t$. For example, $w_{1,1}x_{t-1}x_t \rightarrow \frac{w_{1,1}}{2} (d + e).$
Taking partial derivatives and treating each element $a, b, c, d, e,$ and $f$ as independent yields
$
\begin{align}
J_R(z_t) & = \begin{pmatrix}
w_{1,0} + w_{1,2}f + w_{3,0}c \\
w_{0,1} + w_{2,1} c + w_{0,3} f \\
w_{2,0} + w_{2,1}b + w_{3,0}a + w_{2,2}f + \frac{w_{3,1}}{2}(d + e) + 2 w_{4,0} c \\
\frac{w_{1,1}}{2} + \frac{w_{3,1}}{2}c + \frac{w_{1,3}}{2}f \\
\frac{w_{1,1}}{2} + \frac{w_{3,1}}{2}c + \frac{w_{1,3}}{2}f \\
w_{0,2} + w_{1,2}a + w_{0,3}b + w_{2,2}c + \frac{w_{1,3}}{2}(d+e) + 2w_{0,4}f
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
$
and
$H_R = H_R(z_t) = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & w_{3,0} & 0 & 0 & w_{1,2} \\
0 & 0 & w_{2,1} & 0 & 0 & w_{0,3} \\
w_{3,0} & w_{2,1} & 2w_{4,0} & \frac{w_{3,1}}{2} & \frac{w_{3,1}}{2} & w_{2,2} \\
0 & 0 & \frac{w_{3,1}}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{w_{1,3}}{2} \\
0 & 0 & \frac{w_{3,1}}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{w_{1,3}}{2} \\
w_{1,2} & w_{0,3} & w_{2,2} & \frac{w_{1,3}}{2} & \frac{w_{1,3}}{2} & 2 w_{0,4}
\end{pmatrix} $.
